# How to push a value to an array from within a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Javascript variable :

```
var Item_properties = {
   id : null,
   keys : [],
   hydrate: function() {
       //get data
       this.id = $('input[id=id]').val();

       $("#item_key div input").each(function(index) {
          this.keys.push($(this).val());
       });
}
```

It is impossible to push any data in keys array, I'm getting the message : 
Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7):

jQuery sets `this` to the DOM element in the callback to `.each`. You can save `this` into a variable and then use it.

```
var self = this;
$("#item_key div input").each(function(index) {
  self.keys.push($(this).val()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var $this = this;
$("#item_key div input").each(function (index) {
    $this.keys.push($(this).val());
});
```

Your code didn't worked since the `this` inside the each loop was actually reference to the input tag. But you need to reference the **Item_properties** here.

Answer (score 0):

While [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16317950/887149) other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16317947/887149) are ok, here is another way to do it.

You can use

```
Item_properties.keys.push($(this).val());
```

Instead of

```
this.keys.push($(this).val());
```